# Has my ISP tweaked my modem to prioritise speed tests?

Tags: internet-speed, speedtest

Can it be that my ISP, [Shaw](https://sshaw.ca/), has tweaked my modem to sense when a speed test is run, and then give priority to that test?

It seems that all online tests that use the Ookla's engine give same magnitude numbers as Shaw's own speed test (which is also derived from Ookla) gives.

But, if I use Google or Bell Canada, I get much lower numbers.

[spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQECUT0f2aZ9aFW_dzj7coGtMXTOGM5Gato3XK09nQrQI1jGpqcMzXwCnej085ML1Xe78DMIa7w9XIl/pubhtml)

Does my modem sense that an (Ookla) speed test is run - and artificially prioritise it to boost the perceived performance?

Answer (score 0):

The result of a speed test partly depend on the location and loading of the service's servers.

Your ISP's servers are located closest and are therefore most accurate.

Other services are measuring, in part, speed of their connection to your ISP.

You cannot infer duplicity by your ISP based only on variation on speed test results

Comment: Sound and level-headed, and while I agree with you, I still wouldn't put it past them.

Comment: The issue is that `Google` and `bell.ca` numbers are an order of magnitude worse than the Ookla derivatives speed-tests (see spreadsheet).